# Cells name in excel

Tags: excel

I would give names to cells in excel and use them when I export my file to html.
The problem is that when I use name ranges, only the first cell of the block has the name in the html, and not the following ones.
If I name the cells one by one in excel, it works fine but I have to many cells to do that.
So, my question is : Is there a way in excel to give the same name to all the cells in a block?

Comment: A `Cell` must have a unique name, a `Range` is an area of one or more cells. They are not the same thing, and shouldn't be treated as such.

Comment: Actually I want to be able to define zones in my excel file so that I can find them in the html file.

Comment: Or I guess that if I could name the cells "generically" with names like bla1, bla2, bla3, ... it could help me.

Comment: Did you find anything useful? Please remember posting feedback/comments, so this is useful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named ranges, whereby a name refers to a range of cells, not single cells.

Select the target range, and use *Formulas* -> *Define name*. Enter the name. You will see the range in the field *Refers to*.

[image]

Comment: Am I supposed to see the range in Excel or in the html file ? I didn't mention that I work on mac, so my Excel is a bit different (for example I don't have the "define name" icon).

Comment: @Kaki - In Excel. See the figure in edited answer. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @Kaki - Do you need anything else to consider this "acceptable"?

Comment: The problem is (if I did well what you told) is that I can't find the name of the range in every cell, only in the first one.

Comment: When I give the name "column" to a group of cells (composed by "column1 2 and 3") , in html I have something like : <td .....> <a name = column>column1</a> <td...>column2</td> <td...>column3</td>. Only the first cell has the name. (sorry I  can't post photos yet)

Comment: @Kaki - Could you please specify exactly the process that you are doing? Step by step, literally what menus you traverse. Please post it in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

In the excel file, I select the cells. In the case where the cell name is, as long as I keep clicking on the cells, the name that appears is, for example, D9xD11. But when I "release" the click, the name that appears is only "D9". And I think that is why when I gave the range of cells a new name, it only affects D9.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
Finally I used a macro to name all the cells within a range, with a

```
For Each Cell in MyRange
   Cell.Name = MyString name & i
   i = i + 1
Next Cell
```